# Conflicting declaration (extern base vs. derived)

Tags: c++, inheritance, extern

Simple example:

```
class PublicInterface {}; // e.g. GSM driver with 'send_sms' 
extern PublicInterface theThing; // for most of the code (in common header)

class PrivateImplementation : public PublicInterface {}; // implementation not all need to know about
PrivateImplementation theThing; // the one and only GSM driver with all it needs to work
```

Won't compile, complains that `PrivateImplementation theThing` conflicts with `extern PublicInterface theThing`. OK, I have other options, like having global pointer (`extern PublicInterface *publicThing`) most of the other code can use (and I set it to `publicThing = &theThing` somewhere during initialization). I can also wrap it all in a namespace instead of a class (the device will never have two GSM modules), or *I can play tricks to disable the `extern PublicInterface theThing` for the source with the implementation (and any other that may wish to access something more specific - having `extern PrivateImplementation theThing` instead) and it even works.*

**The question is: why is it an error then?** It just works, when I have `extern PublicInterface theThing` in some sources, `extern PrivateImplementation theThing` in other sources and `PrivateImplementation theThing;` in just one (IAR EWARM - targeting ATSAM4L).

**Possible problems I can think of:**

1. Virtual methods (in derived but not in base class) or multiple-inheritance (the base being second in derived). Small technical problem, but solvable: the linker would need to know under which type it was referenced to inject proper address - may be different (a bit higher) for the public access, which actually lives inside derived (after vmt or first base class). The compiler can work with the pointer (easily convert pointer to derived to pointer to base in that `publicThing = &theThing`) so it *can* (theoretically) do it for global variable - solvable.
2. Method hiding (which could include explicit call to destructor). Not a problem, becase we say in the declaration what we want to see and use (the last declaration wins).
3. Rules which changes are allowed - cannot declare it `int` once and `double` the second time, or it should at least warn.

Is there any real problem? (I mean something unsolvable.)

What could go wrong? (e.g. when I play the trick to use `extern Public...` in some and `extern Private...` in other sources, but never both, never triggering the conflict, getting something that runs properly.)

**EDIT - Response to some comments:**

So, you are basically pointing me to [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). That is at least partial answer to my concerns (yes, stick with the pointer - `publicThing`, do not play tricks). Does not really answer the *why* part, but the example in the link itself shows what problems it could trigger in the compiler (not seeing `CDummy` being two different things in two different sources). Also *luck* that I did not trigger the first problem (multiple-inheritance) I myself mentioned. Still not answering the *why*, but that may be too conceptual for Stack Overflow, right?

Comment: `and it even works` that's still an ODR violation.

Comment: You can't have the two variables in the same scope with the same name.  How would you tell them apart?

Comment: You can't declare something to have different types, that's simply not allowed (nor does it make any sense). And if you use some "tricks" (for example to hide the definition in a separate source file where you don't include the header file that contains the `extern` declaration) then you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `It just works` - That's luck. No, it doesn't. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: _"It just works, when I have..."_ it's still an ODR violation, no diagnostic required; leading to Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: If you want to write code that works, you need to decide what the variable named `theThing` represents! If you want to spend your precious time trying to confuse compilers, then go for it! I don't think the **Stack Overflow** community can really offer advice, if the latter is your chosen path.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<PublicInterface> theThing;` and then `theThing = std::make_unique<PrivateImplementation>();` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think ODR applies here. There is only one definition (`PrivateImplementation theThing;`), everything else is (extern) declarations. The problem is that declaring it not as a pointer, but as an object of type `PublicInterface` tells the compiler that there cannot be any inheritance. The compiler can rightfully assume that the definition will define an object of `PublicInterface` and not of any subclass. It can therefore legally optimize away vrtable lookups.

Comment: @MaxVollmer: Thanks, that is an answer for me :) Rule is one thing (my question is why do we have such a rule, to understand), but you answered the: What could go wrong. Yes, now I understand, the rule is there and it can be used in such a way that my trick could go terribly wrong (like overriding method in the implementation having the compiler call the original or even abstract).

Answer (score 1):

The "why" question is bit hard to understand. The `theThing` is name of object in your code (not pointer or reference to it). C++ is statically typed language and so one object can actually be of only one type. Period. You can have polymorphic pointers or references in C++. So you need to do something like:

```
class PublicInterface {}; // e.g. GSM driver with 'send_sms' 
extern PublicInterface& theThing; // declaration of reference

class PrivateImplementation : public PublicInterface {}; // implementation not all need to know about
PrivateImplementation thing; // the one and only GSM driver with all it needs to work
PublicInterface& theThing = thing; // definition of the reference to thing
```

Comment: That is almost exactly what I was referring to with the pointer (you used reference instead, almost the same thing). I named it `publicThing` (your `theThing`) leaving `theThing` as it is (you renamed it to `thing`). Yes I know, I have it that way already, was just rewriting some old code, which made me wonder... (I can also have one class for everybody, the split was probably to speed-up compilation).

Comment: Reference is simpler to use when you need (possibly polymorphic) alias to actual object. A pointer has pile of operations that are all illegal in your case. Your "why" question felt like you expect the name of object itself already to behave like reference.

Comment: You can use const pointer, but sure, reference is better here (I am rewriting some project which started 15 years ago, still traces of old-school C-like code). My "why" is more about why is it an error and if answer is because it is a rule, then I ask again, why is it a rule, what is the purpose, what can go wrong? MaxVollmer gave me some good answer in a comment (possible optimization). BTW, I want to know why (not just "it is a rule", "because I said so", or "he said", or "standardized"), to understand to remember (I remember things I do understand, not rules, names or numbers).

Comment: Yes, the difference between name of object and reference is that with name of object the compiler must know what the most derived type of it is while reference (like pointer) can be to base class. Most of such subtle complications are for to enable optimizations and so trying to mislead compiler can end with situations where debug build seems to work but release build blows up and no diagnostics what you did wrong.